# procesar json con VUE

Tags: json, vue.js

soy nuevo en Vue y necesito hacer que funcione esto, el ejemplo es tomado de https://www.luisllamas.es/crear-un-interface-web-para-controlar-el-esp8266/ pero lo quiero adaptar para
VUE
Necesito ejecutar la función processReceived para actualizar GPIO

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    var jsonText = '{"command":"updateGPIO","id":D5,"status":"ON"}';
  },

  computed: {

    test() {
      processReceived(jsonText);
    },

  },
  methods: {
    processReceived: function (data) {
    var  json = JSON.parse(data);
      if (json.command == "updateGPIO") {
        updateGPIO(json.id, json.status);
      }
    },

    updateGPIO: function (id, status) {
      document.getElementById("input-label-" + id).textContent = status;

      if (status == "ON") {
        document.getElementById("input-label-" + id).classList.add("On-style");
        document
          .getElementById("input-label-" + id)
          .classList.remove("Off-style");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("input-label-" + id).classList.add("Off-style");
        document
          .getElementById("input-label-" + id)
          .classList.remove("On-style");
      }
    },
  },

})
```

Comment: ¿podrías explicarte mejor?

Comment: Esta mal formulada esta pregunta. Especifica el problema o el error.

Comment: La funcion computada debe devolver un valor. agregale                                      
 return processReceived(jsonText);

Answer (score 0):

para ejecutar la funcion `processReceived()` puedes colocar un boton dentro del div `#app` que lance dicha funcion:

```
<button @click="processReceived()">Ejecutar</button>
```

También podrías hacer que la función tome directamente los datos de `data` sin recibir parametros:

```
processReceived: function () {
    var  json = JSON.parse(this.jsonText);
      if (json.command == "updateGPIO") {
        updateGPIO(json.id, json.status);
      }
    }
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.